# How to do NLP fill-mask with restricted possible inputs

Tags: nlp, mask, huggingface

I want to use NLP to fill in a masked word in a text, but instead of choosing from all possible words I want to find which is the more likely of two candidate words. For example, imagine I have a sentence "The [MASK] was stuck in the tree" and I want to evaluate whether "kite" or "bike" is the more likely word.

I know how to find the globally most probable words using hugging face's fill-mask pipeline

```py
from transformers import pipeline, AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForMaskedLM

# Define the input sentence with a masked word
input_text = "The [MASK] was stuck in the tree"

# Load the pre-trained model and tokenizer
model_name = "bert-base-cased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

# Tokenize the input sentence
tokenized_text = tokenizer.tokenize(input_text)

# Use the pipeline to generate a list of predicted words and probabilities
mlm = pipeline("fill-mask", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
results = mlm(input_text)

# Print outputs
for result in results:
    token = result["token_str"]
    print(f"{token:<15} {result['score']}")
```

However if "bike" and "kite" arent in the first few most probable words this doesnt help.

How can I use fill-mask to find the probability of specific masks?

P.S. I'm not sure if overflow is the best place to post this question, there doesnt seem to be a place for nlp specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a direct way to feed two candidates into "fill-mask" however if we dive into the underlying model on which "fill-mask" is built on we can find the probability of the other words given our candidate.

```py
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForMaskedLM
from torch.nn.functional import softmax

# Load the pre-trained model and tokenizer
model_name = "bert-base-cased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

# Define the input sentence with a masked word
input_text = "The [MASK] was stuck in the tree."
candidates = ["fancy hot dog", "dog", "cat", "bird", "run"]

# Tokenize the input sentence
tokenized_text = tokenizer.tokenize(input_text)
mask_token_index = tokenized_text.index("[MASK]")

# Function to calculate the probability of a candidate
def get_candidate_probability(candidate_tokens):

    # Replace the masked token with the candidate tokens
    tokenized_candidate = ["[CLS]"] + tokenized_text[:mask_token_index] + candidate_tokens + tokenized_text[mask_token_index + 1:]

    # Convert tokenized sentence to input IDs
    input_ids = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenized_candidate)

    # Convert input IDs to tensors
    input_tensor = torch.tensor([input_ids])

    # Get the logits from the model
    with torch.no_grad():
        logits = model(input_tensor).logits[0]

    # Calculate the probability of the candidate word
    probs = softmax(logits, dim=-1)
    probs = probs[range(len(input_ids)), input_ids]
    prob = (
        torch.prod(probs[1:mask_token_index+1])
        * torch.prod(probs[mask_token_index+len(candidate_tokens)+1:])
    )

    return prob.item()

# Evaluate the probability of each candidate word
for candidate in candidates:
    candidate_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(candidate)
    candidate_probability = get_candidate_probability(candidate_tokens)
    print(f"{candidate:<20} {candidate_probability}")
```

Here for each candidate we replace the mask with the candidate's tokens, we get the ID of each token and feed it into the model. The model spits out a `(batch_size,sentence_size,vocab_size)` where the i,j,k'th element corresponds to the un-normalized log probability of having the k'th token of the vocab in the j'th spot in the sentence of batch i. We softmax the logits along the vocab dimension then pick out the probability of each token in the sentence. We finally multiply all the probability of the words outside of the mask to get the probability of each word given the candidate fill-in for the mask.